# What are the common attributes of K5 and K3,3?

Tags: graph-theory

K5 and K3,3 are the basic nonplanar graphs.  K5 is as same as K3,3 when respecting planar graph. So I have a question: What are the common attributes of K5 and K3,3? Which functions make f(K5)=f(K3,3)?

Comment: http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/01/graph-minor-theory-part-2/

Comment: Your question would be perhaps more appropriate for math.stackexchange.  The main problem with your question is it's largely subjective. 

Comment: Thank you! perhaps to think question like this is a bad habit.

Comment: It is a bit vague but otherwise quite a good (research level) question.

Comment: Unfortunately due to being closed I am not able to make this as an answer: crossing number. They have crossing number 1, and because of this the K5-minor-free graphs and the K3,3-minor-free graphs have a structural decomposition that's nicer than other minor closed families that don't have a 1-crossing excluded minor.